# What is the difference between setting autofocus to true and to request focus?

Tags: flutter, dart, focus, autofocus

I read in documentation that requestFocus() request primary focus. Does setting autofocus to true behaves similarly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When set auto focus true, whenever state will build or re-build focus will automatic shift to that element if any other elements are not holding focus, while if you are calling `requestFocus` this will set `primary focus` to that
particular focus node.

Note- if you are calling `FocusNode().requestFocus()` that will remove focus form that screen because FocusNode() is not associated with any widget in tree